# How to generate Map of Map in Swagger?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I am using Swagger 3 (OpenAPI 3) and 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' 2.19.2 to generate Java code for controllers and models.

I have next controller method

```
public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getContent()
```

I need to describe this response in the yml.

Tried this option:

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: successful operation
      content:
        '*/*':
          schema:
            type: object
            additionalProperties:
              type: object
              additionalProperties:
                type: string
```

But this generates next interface:

```
default ResponseEntity<Map<String, Map<String>> getContent
```

so obviously this code has compilation error.

I tried other options for yml - nothing works.

Could you please clarify - how properly declare map of map in swagger yml ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did  you look at this : https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/
I think you could use a $ref here

Answer (score 0):

Your OpenAPI definition is correct.

The issue seems to be a bug in the code generator that you use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please advice which generator to use then ? I thought 'org.hidetake.swagger.generator' is proper choice.